# Design deprecation warning to replace a list with vararg

Tags: kotlin, type-inference, deprecation-warning

I have the following methods:

```kotlin
fun RowVector(x: Double, y: Double): RowVector2 = RowVector(listOf(x, y)) as RowVector2
fun RowVector(x: Double, y: Double, z: Double): RowVector3 = RowVector(listOf(x, y, z)) as RowVector3
fun RowVector(vararg elements: Double): RowVector = RowVector(elements.asList())

fun RowVector(elements: List<Double>): RowVector = // Actually creates the RowVector instance
```

While there are some legitimate use-cases to call `RowVector(elements: List<Double>)`, I would like to encourage callers to use the `vararg` version of the method, as this allows the compiler to do some smarter type inference, like here:

```kotlin
val vector1 = RowVector(listOf(0.0, 1.0, 2.0)) // Type is inferred to be RowVector
val vector2 = RowVector(0.0, 1.0, 2.0) // Compiler can see that only 3 values are passed and therefore infers RowVector3
```

I am therefore adding a `@Deprecated` annotation to `RowVector(elements: List<Double>)` which suggests the caller to rather use the `vararg` version, but can easily be suppressed if the use-case is actually legitimate.

The issue that I am facing is with the design of the `ReplaceWith` part of the `@Deprecated` annotation. I would like the IDE to replace `RowVector(listOf(0.0, 1.0, 2.0))` with `RowVector(0.0, 1.0, 2.0)`, but so far, I have not found a way to do that:

```kotlin
@Deprecated(
    "Prefer the vararg interface if possible as it allows the compiler to infer types better.",
    ReplaceWith("RowVector(*elements.toDoubleArray())")
)
```

leads to `RowVector(*listOf(0.0, 1.0, 2.0).toDoubleArray())`, which still requires manual clean-up.

```kotlin
@Deprecated(
    "Prefer the vararg interface if possible as it allows the compiler to infer types better.",
    ReplaceWith("RowVector(*doubleArrayOf(elements))")
)
```

weirdly does nothing and

```kotlin
@Deprecated(
    "Prefer the vararg interface if possible as it allows the compiler to infer types better.",
    ReplaceWith("RowVector(*elements)")
)
```

does a literal replacement like so: `RowVector(*listOf(0.0, 1.0, 2.0))`.

I know that this is a first-world problem and that the caller can just read the warning and remove the `listOf()` quite easily, but I would nevertheless try to make it as easy as possible for the caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely this is just not possible, sadly.

In your example, you declare the `List<Double>` directly inside the function call. However, this is not the only way to call the function.

For example, I could declare the `List` inside a `val`ue first.

```kotlin
val foo = listOf(0.0)
RowVector(foo)
```

In case you were able to declare a replacement using `ReplaceWith` that would extract the values from the `List` provided, the IDE effectively would need to inline the declaration, possibly altering behaviour.

In addition, the `List` could be the result of a function call, which would make a automatic replacement even more problematic.

```kotlin
val random = Random()
fun fooFun() = List(random.nextInt(0, Int.MAX_VALUE)) { random.nextDouble() }

RowVector(fooFun())
```

As the outcome of this code is (nearly) random, I don't see how a replacement could work here.

Personally, I would just leave out the `ReplaceWith` entirely in this case and rather provide a good `message` with clues on how to properly change the code manually.

Comment: The cases that you mention are exactly the ones where a call to the `List`-variant would be legitimate, however they seem to be fairly rare in my experience, while the case where values are directly declared with a `listOf` call seem to be more common. Either way, I did end up going with just a message right now. Cheers :)